# jquery after method replacing entire page elements and not the selector

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I'm grabbing the data on the right and trying to place it below the image to the left. When I use the function the entire document gets overwritten.

```
var product_shop = jQuery('.product-shop');

jQuery('.product-img-box #image').after(product_shop[0].outerHTML);
```

Site URL: http://www.mjtrim.com/greek-key/33mm-greek-key-jacquard.html#colors

No matter what method I use insertAfter, etc, I get the same result.

Comment: please use `$` instead of `jQuery` <3 save all those precious bits

Comment: Why are you using outerHTML?

Comment: ^ Stick with jQuery once you start unless absolutely necessary. Also, what is `product_shop[0]` supposed to be (like what on the page)

Comment: if i just use html() i don't get the <div class="product-shop"></div> wrapper. html() uses the innerHTML method but I want the containing element as well.. that's why i use [0].outerHTML

Comment: `$("#this").parent().html();` does this work?

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: try running it in the console and you'll see what i mean.

Comment: it is because of the script elements within the `.product-shop` element

Comment: Try `var product_shop = jQuery('.product-shop'); product_shop.find('script').remove(); jQuery('.product-img-box #image').after(product_shop);`

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny it worked. Why does this happen? and more importantly when i add back the scripts to the new element will they run as normal?

Comment: a better choice will be to remove all the inlined script and add it to a separate script file and include it at the bottom of the html

Comment: i can't edit the actual content of the server. one of the limitations. it must be done via javascript. how can i add the script back to the element? this won't work "var product_shop_scripts = product_shop.find('script'); jQuery('.product-shop').append(product_shop_scripts);"

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".product-img-box #image").after("<div>" 
     + $(".product-shop").html() + "</div>");
```

**edit: now adds the required text after the image.**

Not entirely sure if it does what you want, but it's worth a try. Do you want the entire `.product-shop` box or just the description text?

Comment: "trying to place it below the image to the left"

Comment: There are multiple images on the page that are "to the left"

Comment: the largest product image that's to the left.

Comment: i get the same result with the update. try running that code in the build in console of ff or chrome. you might have to change the '$' to 'jQuery'.

Comment: Is that part of the page dynamically generated, meaning it wouldn't be there when the `$(stuff)` is bound?